# How do I totally remove the "follow" functionality on Odoo/OpenERP?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

I'm talking about the `follow` button under users. Can this be done with Access control without modifying the views?

Comment: I don't think so bro, you must change the views

Comment: Without modifying views, we cann't do anything. If we want to change view than we must to do some customization or modification in view files. Suggestion, We can create one security group. User with that access rights can only use *follow* functionality and from the other User it will be restrict.

Comment: Good suggestion @Odedra! Which model do i restrict to resctric the follow functionality.

Comment: You can put restrictions on the "mail.followers" model.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Alexander Suraphel,

In your form view of our object at the bottom you will find following syntax :

```
        <div class="oe_chatter">
            <field name="message_follower_ids" widget="mail_followers"/>
            <field name="message_ids" widget="mail_thread"/>
        </div>
```

in this :

here `message_follower_ids` add the follow feature so you can remove that line, and that will remove that feature from that object on that view.

Thanks